# Is it possible to use Angular2 or Aurelia with IIS and without having node.js and NPM installed?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, angular, aurelia

The reason why I ask if either Angular2 or Aurelia can be used without having node.js and NPM installed is because we can only deploy to windows IIS servers at work. We cannot have Node.Js or NPM installed on the servers, but I'd like to leverage the productivity of either A-framework, but it looks from pluralsight courses and suchlike that I need to have Node and NPM installed.

Ideally I'd like to develop my Aurelia or Angular 2 app using TypeScript in Visual Studio. Is this possible without Node/NPM or am I missing a trick ?

Comment: Notice that you will miss an important feature, Angular Universal without support from Node.

Answer (score 3):

You can very well deploy Angular2 or Aurelia application on IIS , and it does not need Node to run.

Having said that, To reach the deployment ready version of your code, you need to compile Typescript\Less files, may be you want to optimize using bundling\minifying your code.

To do this you need some sort of Task runner, Gulp\Grunt are very good in doing that. There is Angular-Cli which also takes care of this. And these tool runs on Node. So for development you need it.

But the final application will be just JS\HTML\CSS or some static content you don't need Node, it can be served from IIS also.

Comment: Awesome thank you. That explains a lot. I did wonder if there was a way and I was missing something important