# can I start using angular 2 without node?

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2015

I want to try angular 2 for **[VS 2015](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)** but the first prerequisite is `node.js`.

If I understand correct, I need `node.js` as webserver and `npm` to download package?

Can I do the same with IIS and VS nu-get?

Comment: Node (using npm) is an easy way to get dependent packages. Also since Agular2 is a front-end framework, you can host it on any webserver.

Comment: @crashmstr So the answer is I need node.js because the packages?

Comment: Installing node.js is typical so you can use npm to install packages to use in your Angular site. Some unit test frameworks may use node to run in as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Angular2 or Aurelia with IIS and without having node.js and NPM installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079582/is-it-possible-to-use-angular2-or-aurelia-with-iis-and-without-having-node-js-an)

Comment: @crashmstr what is the not typical way? I used to work with nuget package. so going back to command line isnt my first choice. And I just download/install node.js and didnt  install the latest version or  the recomend npm version. So not really impress so far.

Comment: You should see if you can find a different tutorial to work with then.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Angular 2 apps just fine in Visual Studio (with some configuration, which can be painful). You can also serve Angular 2 apps in IIS (or any other web server for that matter). However to manage the packages Angular 2 uses, and to provide a light-wight web server you can use in development, using NodeJs is the easiest and the recommended way.

NuGet and npm are similar products in the fact that they both provide a way to package files and create software packages. NuGet runs separately through the command line or inside VisualStudio, while npm comes with NodeJS and is Node's built in package manager that you cannot run without having NodeJS.

Here is the Visual Studio Quick Start provided by the Angular team: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Answer (score 0):

I develop in Visual Studio 2015 all the time without NPM. I have my systemjs.config set to load angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap and others from CDN at unpkg.com. Few quirks but it works just fine for development.